# Perl in-place substitution

Tags: regex, perl

In Perl one liner, we can use the `-i` argument to do an in-place substitution. What's the equivalence of `-i` when writing perl code in the IDE?

Consider the following code:

```
binmode(STDOUT, ':raw');
open my $fh, '<', $filename;
while (<$fh>) {
    s/^/<rootroot>/ if $.==1;
    if (/(<link rel[^<>\n]*?)(\/?)(>)/g) {
        my ($p1, $p2, $p3) = ($1, $2, $3);
        s/$p1$p2$p3/($p2 ? qq|$p1$p2$p3<span class="entry">| : qq|$p1\/$p3<span class="entry">|)/ge;
    };
    s/<\/>/<entry_end><\/entry_end>/;
    s/$/<\/rootroot>/ if eof;

}
```

How can we save all the lines of changes in-place?

Because I need to do a quick validation on the html file using XML::LibXML right after the in-place change of the html source..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `local $^I = '';`

Comment: Thanks @ikegami for your comment. I'm a bit confused. How should I use the `$^I` properly? This is the first time I heard of this. Or can you point me to some reference articles that I can check on? :)

Comment: `-i` literally adds `$^I = '';`. The thing is, you're probably used to pairing it with `-p`. So maybe you want to look into what `-p` adds. If only that was mentioned in the [documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)...

Comment: I'm using `binmode(STDOUT, ':raw'); ` not sure if this will affect the `$^I = '';`

Comment: You shouldn't be using STDOUT, so that's no good. `binmode(select())` inside the loop should work, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
my $filename = 'test.dat';
@ARGV = ($filename);
$^I = '';
while(<<>>) {
    binmode(ARGV, ':raw');
    # Do the substitiution on $_ here ...
    print;
}
```

I did not find out how to set `binmode` before the loop, since `ARGV` is only defined after the `<>` operator has been used.

- The `$^I` and `ARGV`variables are decribed in [`perlvar`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)
- See [perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) for information about why you should use `<<>>` instead of `<>`.

#### Some notes:

- The `while(<>) { ... }`
  According to [perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html), the loop

> ```
> while (<>) {  ...         # code for each line
> }
> ```
>
> is equivalent to the following Perl-like pseudo code:
>
> ```
> unshift(@ARGV, '-') unless @ARGV;   
> while ($ARGV = shift) { 
>     open(ARGV, $ARGV);
>     while (<ARGV>) {    
>        ...        # code for each line    
>     }  
> }
> ```

- Using in-place edit without a backup file: `$^I=""`:

According to [perlrun](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html):

> If no extension is supplied, and your system supports it, the original
>   file is kept open without a name while the output is redirected to a
>   new file with the original filename. When perl exits, cleanly or not,
>   the original file is unlinked.

and some more information in [this](https://backreference.org/2011/01/29/in-place-editing-of-files/) blog:

> Perl opens and immediately unlink()s the original file, then opens a
>   new file with the same name (new file descriptor and inode), and sends
>   output to this second file; at the end, the old file is closed and
>   thus deleted because it was unlinked, and what's left is a changed
>   file with the same name as the original.

See also [doio.c](https://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/HEAD:/doio.c#l1191) for actual implementation.

- According to the above, the following might work:

  ```
  my $fn = 'test.dat';
  open ( my $fh, '<:raw', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
  unlink $fn or die "$!";
  open ( my $fh2, '>:raw', $fn ) or die "Could not reopen file '$fn': $!";
  while(<$fh>) {
      # Do the substitutions on $_ here ...
      print $fh2 $_;
  }
  close $fh;
  close $fh2;
  ```

Comment: Re "*I did not find out how to set binmode before the loop*", You can't. You can add `:encoding` using `use open ':std', ':encoding(...)';`, but there's no way to tell `use open` to default to "binary" handles